# Atribuir link a uma janela modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Como faço para ter o link de uma janela modal?
No caso quero enviar este link, o usuário ao clicar no link já abra direto o modal.
Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possível solução

Uma opção é usar `hashtag` para informar que o cliente quer abrir um `modal`, exemplo:

> www.sitedevendas.com/produto#comprar

Dessa forma você saberia que o cliente quer abrir o `modal` **comprar** e assim você deve analisar em `window.location.href` se existe `#comprar` nessa *string*.

---

### Exemplo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#comprar') != -1) {
    $('#comprar').modal('show');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Passe um parametro pelo link:

exemplo: `http://dominio.com/nome_pagina_modal.html?par=open`

Na sua aplicação coloque esse script (operador condicional (ternário)):

```
location.href.split("=").pop() == "open" ? $('#bannerformmodal').modal('show') : null;
```

- `location.href;` retorna a URL da página atual
- `split("=").pop();` pega a parte após o sinal de =
- `Operador Ternário` - se a condição `location.href.split("=").pop() == "open"`  é true, o operador retornará o valor `$('#bannerformmodal').modal('show')` se não, ele retorna o valor `null;`.

Comment: Ou melhor, não precisa converter o location.href em string, pq ele já é string. Dá pra eliminar uma linha ali.

Comment: var parametro = (location.href).split("=").pop();

Comment: aha.. bota no exemplo funcional pra gente ver

Comment: @ÐvÐ postado no server

Comment: Só o oro.. rsss.. ficou bem melhor na minha opinião

Comment: De 20 linhas restou apenas 1 rsrs